# Missing spring boot dependency 'spring-integration-mail'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

In my Spring Boot (`2.1.6.RELEASE`) project I have added following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But still the following is missing `spring-integration-mail`, should it not be included automatically?

Full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.test.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>email-ci-trigger</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: post you full pom

Comment: Try to clean and re-install pom dependencies.

Comment: check transitive dependencies, spring-integration-mail may not refered by your dependencies

Comment: check with this command mvn dependency:tree it will prints a tree representation of your project dependencies, if spring-integration-mail included or not

Comment: As pointed out by @MohitSharma, checking dependency tree with maven is probably your best bet on checking if a dependency is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration starter only pulls in the `spring-integration-core` jar; otherwise you would have many unnecessary jars on your classpath, slowing your application startup.

The mail starter does not know anything about spring integration; it is for when you want to use mail without spring integration

You need to add other integration modules manually:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The version will be managed for you.